# Запуск функции при изменении переменной, без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, менялось значение переменной на любое, но важно чтобы при нажатии так же перезапускалась функция пагинации, то есть чтобы генерировалось такое поле, но уже учитывая измененные значения.

[image: 1]

```
var cnt_goods = 20;
$(function() {

    $('#light-pagination').pagination({
        items: cnt_goods,
        itemsOnPage: 4,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme'
    });
});
```

Comment: и что вам мешает повторно вызвать эту пагинацию?

Comment: Значение какой переменной? Какое поле должно генерироваться? Из Вашего вопроса я понял лишь то, что вы хотите делать что-то (постраничная навигация?) без перезагрузки страницы. В приведённом Вами коде, как я понял, происходит инициализация плагина jQuery при загрузке страницы. Прочитайте документацию к нему. Вполне возможно существуют опции для работы с AJAX без собственных велосипедов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по названию вы используете плагин [simplePagination](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/), посмотрите документацию, там можно задать обработчик события `onPageClick` и есть методы `destroy` и `redraw`, думаю с их помощью вы сможете пересоздать пагинацию с учетом изменения